# Please tell me about the trading function OrderOpenTime in the MQL4 Meta Editor

Tags: mql4, mt4

I was writing code in MQL4 Meta Editor.
I wrote the code in such a way that it is possible to open both a buy and a sell position.
I tried to calculate the date and time of the candle that I entered with the trading function OrderOpenTime, but I don't know how to calculate the date and time of both buy and sell if the entry is both buy and sell.
I need your help.

Add the code I are currently writing
I'm sorry if my native language is Japanese and the English is strange.

```
for(int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES) == false) break;

if(OrderMagicNumber() != MagicNumber) continue;

if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol()) continue;

oder_shift = iBarShift(Symbol(),Period(),OrderOpenTime() , false );

}
```

Comment: Please show your code. Without this, you will not get much, if any, help. Also ensure you have read the docs for the function which should be your first action [OrderOpenTime()](http://example.com))

Comment: Add the code I are currently writing
I'm sorry if my native language is Japanese and the English is strange.